# using Paley-Wiener to get support and then estimate inf sup

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

Define the function
$$ \tilde{f}_n(\omega)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{\sin R\omega/2}{R\omega/2} s_n(R\omega/2\pi),$$
where (using the Weierstrass product representation for $\sin$)
$$ s_n(w) = \frac{\sin \pi w}{\pi w} \prod_{j=1}^n\left( 1-\frac{w^2}{j^2}\right)^{-1}= \prod_{j=n+1}^\infty \left( 1-\frac{w^2}{j^2}\right)^{-1}.$$

I want to show that the Fourier transform $f_n(t)$ of $ \tilde{f}_n(\omega)$ has support $[-R,R],$ and the idea is to use Paley-Wiener theorem:
in order to do that, I should find a bound
$$\tilde{f}_n(z)\leq C e^{R|z|}$$
for all $z$ in the complex plane. Any idea? (I was able to find something on $\sin z/z$ separately, but this doesn't seem to be enough.)

Moreover, the next step is to show that,
for every $m \geq 0,$ the mass bound
$$ \inf_n \sup_{|w| \geq m} |s_n(w)| \leq 4^{1−m}$$
holds,
for which I haven't any idea at the moment.